# Cannot set pivot point for circle

Tags: modeling, workflow, origin

I have a circle
[image: Circle]

This circle was created from long cube using a Simple Deform modifier.
[image: object with Simple Deform modifier]

The problem is than I cannot set pivot point directly to the center of circle.

I've tried all the set origin options, but none of them put pivot to the center. (Almost all of them put it as shown on the first pic) I assume that this is because of simple deform usage. Are there any ways to put pivot to the center of circle? 
(Blend file of the circle - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6PGztAwS3kKmWvQFPws0XdZtyINKymS/view?usp=sharing)
Or if there are other ways how I can design circle with 4 edges with right angle between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this non-destructive workflow, your object is still considered by Blender to be the original little cube: the *Simple Deform* just "happens" to it, and can be still tweaked, changed, removed. The circle is not really there, is just "computed" on the go from the starting cube every time.

This saves memory and allows "customizability", but requires you to think of the object as a little cube with some *other thing* happening to it. It becomes very clear if you enter in *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and realize that you only have the original cube's vertices only.

If you want to set the transformation in stone, and have your actual circle with all its vertices, you can hit **"*Apply*" in the modifier** options. After doing that, you can **use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > "*Set Origin: To Center of Mass*"** to correctly place the pivot to the object's center.

---

P.S. there are alternative ways to create a square-section circle: e.g. using the Spin tool or the Spin modifier, or using a Bezier Circle with a square Bevel object, or this one (I think it's the easiest) that starts with a torus:

- Add a Torus
- In the "new object" parameters (<kbd>F6</kbd>) change "*Minor Segments*" to 8
- In *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) select the unwanted edge loops (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Mouse Select</kbd>)
- <kbd>X</kbd> > "*Dissolve Edges*"

[image]

All these methods have the pivot in the right place